# Drag down the question indefinitely when editing answer

Tags: bug, edits, answers

How to reproduce the bug:

1. Answer a question/go to a question that you have answered.
2. Click "Edit"
3. Drag the slider down.
   [image]

I think this is a bug because it doesn't make sense to be able to drag this slider down indefinitely. The slider should lock when it has reached the end of the original question.